# exception thrown: TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'createVertexArray' (emscripten)

Tags: javascript, c++, webgl, microsoft-edge, emscripten

I've created a simple SDL2 & Opengl ES2 demo. It works in Chrome and Firefox, but in Edge I get this error:

```
exception thrown: TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'createVertexArray'
```

The C++ code, where the exception is thrown:

```
// Create Vertex Array Object
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArrayOES(vao);
```

Is it my fault, or a bug of the Edge browser or Emscripten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open a console and type

```
document.createElement('canvas').getContext("webgl").getSupportedExtensions();
```

What does it print?

Likely edge doesn't support the [`OES_vertex_array_object` extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_vertex_array_object/).

There's a polyfill for it here

https://github.com/greggman/oes-vertex-array-object-polyfill

Comment: I've added the polyfill to the generated HTML file: `<script src="OES.js"></script>` But it is still not listed in the extension list

Comment: BTW at least on my machine Edge still requires "experimental-webgl" and reports version "0.96" which means as far as Edge it's concerned it still beta as far as WebGL support.

Comment: if you look inside it looks like you need to call setupVertexArrayObject with your WebGLRenderingContext – gman 1 hour ago   delete

Comment: Here's another https://github.com/greggman/oes-vertex-array-object-polyfill that doesn't need to have init called